# loading page in Flask

Tags: python, flask, loading

I am a bit new to Flask.

My home.html is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welkom bij het Flask-project</h1>
    <form action="/process_form" method="POST">
        <label for="key_pressed">Voer de key_pressed waarde in:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="key_pressed" name="key_pressed"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Verzenden">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My Flask function (app.py) is as follows:

```
@app.route('/process_form', methods=['POST'])
def process_form():
    key_pressed = request.form['key_pressed']
    return render_template('loading_page.html')
    def generate_plot():
        # Voeg hier je code toe om 'key_pressed' naar het dummy1.py-script te sturen en de plot te genereren
        
        # Voorbeeldplot maken
        x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        y1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
        time.sleep(3)
        plt.plot(x1, y1)
        plt.xlabel('X-as')
        plt.ylabel('Y-as')
        plt.title('Gegenereerde plot 1')
        plt.savefig('static/plot.png')  # Opslaan als plot.png in de 'static'-map
        
    thread = threading.Thread(target=generate_plot, args=(key_pressed,))
    thread.start()
    print(key_pressed)
    return render_template('results.html', key_pressed=key_pressed)
```

As you can see I would like to show a loading_page.html during the plotting time. When the plotting is finished, it must direct to results.html to show the results. For this example I have add a delay of 3 seconds because the plotting goes very fast (my plotting function is in reality much more complicated and takes more time).

However, only the loading_page.html shows up and I'm not directed to results.html after 3 seconds (i.e. when plotting is finished in this case). Can someone please help me how I can fix this?

Comment: You have two `return`s one after another: once the code reach the first one, it does exit from the `process_from()` function. Thus, the thread you are trying to create it wont ever start

Comment: Once you `return render_template('loading_page.html')` Flask is done serving that request. To redirect to some other page, you would need to handle that in javascript or a meta tag on the loading page. Probably what you really want to to directly return the results page and then have that page use javascript to poll for the file or use a push solution

Answer (score 0):

the code after the first `return` will never be read by python.

The return value is the only content which can be sent to the client.

The easy way is to have no loading page

```py
@app.route('/process_form', methods=['POST'])
def process_form():
    # get key
    time.sleep(3) # generate plot
    return 'sleep 3 sec'
```

But making a customer wait is not a good practice

Another solution is to embed javascript code in the response so that the client does the calculation on his computer if the calculation is not too large.

If the calculation is important, the first request records the client's input and begins to calculate the result and returns a loading page which will contact a second API route (by javascript) to retrieve the result

Comment: Thanks for your help. The 3 seconds delay is just to delay this simple plotting proces. In reality my plotting code takes approx. 1 minute. During this minute I want to show a loading_page. When the plotting is finished, the result.html must be shown. With other words: the 3 seconds is just randomly chosen to illustrate and try this simple code. When it works to show a loading_page.html during this simple plotting proces, I would like to add my (complex  and time consuming) plotting code

Comment: Yes, I understand, maybe you can try the other two solutions I mentioned at the end of my answer.
I don't know any other way.
This problem is related to the HTTP protocol which has the principle of sending one or more resources but not of maintaining contact and then sending other resources